# Table iteration using WATIR

Tags: ruby, watir

There is a table in my page which I need handle, For that I am using the following code

```
b.table(:id,'something').rows.each_with_index do |row,index|
    puts row.cell(:index,1).text
    if index.eql?3
        row.cell(:index,0).image.click
    end
end
```

It works fine unless the table shrinks and expands. In first column of my table there is 'plus' button, If I click that button, table expands and it shows more number of rows, Once clicked it become 'minus' symbol, If I click that 'minus' symbol again, it again shrinks. My problem is, If expand the table by clicking the plus button(as shown in the program where I clicking when index reaches to 3), then rest of the rows(from 4 rows) are not executed. As for as I know Object location changes I guess, So to get all the rows, once again I need to execute 'b.table(:id,'something').rows', So that newly expanded table is working fine, So Is anyway Can I avoid this problem without terminating the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you call `b.table(:id,'something').rows` then the rows is already a fixed ruby array. <del>Nothing underneath can change that array and if you try to change that array inside the loop, ruby will most probably complain.</del>

So you have two options:

1. call `table.rows` again
2. call `b.button(...).click` and then only once call `table.rows`

Hope this helps.

additional clarification: no, it is not possible to perform what you want. `#rows` actually returns `Watir::ElementCollection`, `#each_with_index` calls `#each` and if you look at `#each` source, you will see:

```
def each(&blk)
  to_a.each(&blk)
end
```

`#to_a` generates a new array object with the elements. Basically you get an array of rows and iterate over them. Watir **fortunately** does not try to be smart and change the array you requested from under your feet when the page changes. It's actually a very bad idea to change an array while iterating over it. Results would be unpredictable. That's why you need to call `table(...).rows` each time you want to see current page state.

As I said though, it is not necessary to iterate over the table to click your button. You can reach it directly by `xpath` or `css`.

Comment: <<Once you call b.table(:id,'something').rows then the rows is already a fixed ruby array>>

      Yes I know. 

<<call table.rows>> This is what I am doing, But I feel like every time table shrinks and expand then I have to call b.table.rows.

Comment: hi, What you have explained additionally I understood already, I got it the fact that it's taken into the array, it wouldn't change whenever the page refreshes, But what you explained in the last line is not clear to me, "As I said though, it is not necessary to iter................" Are you saying we could point out a particular row using xpath?

Comment: @RAJ, I don't know off the top of my head about reaching particular cell in a table with xpath, but it should be possible. Also you can reach your button by `name`, `id`, `text`, `class` or other attributes and avoid dealing with the table cells.

Comment: Hi Thanks, I would do.